# IOS - Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ios, rubygems, cocoapods

I uninstalled cocoapods with command `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`. later i treid to install by using command `sudo gem install cocoapods`, error is shown as below

```
Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/json-2.1.0/ext/json/ext/generator
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0 -r ./siteconf20190929-29689-1blhfxj.rb extconf.rb
Ignoring bigdecimal-1.3.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 1.3.5
Ignoring bigdecimal-1.3.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 1.3.4
Ignoring bigdecimal-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 1.3.2
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Do you know to how to fix that?

Comment: did you try as an error message says? - gem pristine bigdecimal --version 1.3.5

Comment: with a message, it seems ruby is either not installed or not the correct version